# MQTT - Paho IMqttMessageLIstener misses messages when the listener thread is blocked for an operation

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I have a simple MQTT listener that subscribes to a topic and call back

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient(mqttHost, MqttClient.generateClientId());
            client.connect();    
            client.subscribe("test", QUALITY_OF_SERVICE_2, new IMqttMessageListener() {
                public void messageArrived(final String s, final MqttMessage mqttMessage) {

System.out.println("Received"+mqttMessage.toString());
// Code that blocks the thread 
lock.lock();
//do something
lock.unlock();

});
```

Lets say i am publishing 1000 messages to the topic test but running the above listener on tomcat would display < 1000 console outputs showing that the receiver thread is not getting all the sent messages.

Without the lock() code, the listener works as expected and receives all messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing long running/blocking tasks in the `messageArrived` handler, as this is called on the main network loop of the client.

If you have long running/blocking tasks to do with a message you should create a local queue and process the messages from that queue with either a single local thread if message order is important, or a pool of threads if you want to handle the incoming messages as quickly as possible.

Java has a built in set of core classes for building queues and starting threads to consume messages from those queues. Look at the classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: This was the issue. I used ExecutorService to spin up executor threads to process incoming messages and the flow worked as expected.